How to generate 4 bit LUT for Reduced-Complexity Box-Plus Decoder(RCBP) of LDPC?
in Ryan and Shu Lin's book, they proposed a decode method named RCBP, for 5 bit input, the quantized B table $\hat{\tau}(r, c)$ with $r \geq c$ is:
$d = r - c$, if $c > 1$, $|\hat{\tau}| = (c-1) + (d > 2)$, else $|\hat{\tau}| = (d > 1) \& (c_0)$, where $c_0$ is the LSB bit of $c$, this code is correct for 5 bit input, however, it works wrong for 4 bit input, so the question is: how to generate the correct $|\hat{\tau}|$ value for 4 bit or even 3 bit input? great thanks.
